# Data manipulation without server side

Tags: jquery, html, xhtml

I have to create a very simple webpage to show, filter and add data from not-yet-defined source (probably txt/xml/cvs). Records should be visible as a table, filtered using 3 criteria fields. There should be also possibility to add new records.

My first thought was: XHTML + jQuery + csv2table + PicNet Table Filter. It does exactly what I want except adding rows - that is saving changes in source file (probably due to security risk).

My question is - is there any possibility to do it without involving server side like asp.net, Java EE, php, sql? Source file is located on the server.

Thanks for your ideas :-)

Answer (score 1):

use [Data Table](http://datatables.net/) instead of PicNet..it does all the thing which you have written in your question..

Answer (score 1):

No. Web browsers cannot save data to a remote server without the server providing a mechanism for them to do it with.

The closest you could come would be to use a server that supports HTTP PUT and an authentication mechanism that you deem good enough, although with a browser that allows you to make PUT requests using XHR. This still requires the server to co-operate, but just requires server configuration and no server side programming.